# How to change post parameters to json raw format

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.6

I am using FOSRestBundle for build a Restful API. I have this code for a POST Restful service:

```
/**
 * Create a new session.
 * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
 *
 * @ApiDoc(
 *   resource = true,
 *   https = true,
 *   description = "Create a new session",
 *   statusCodes = {
 *      200 = "Returned when successful",
 *      400 = "Returned when errors"
 *   }
 * )
 *
 * @RequestParam(name="username", nullable=false, strict=true, description="The username")
 * @RequestParam(name="veevaToken", nullable=false, strict=true, description="The token")
 * @RequestParam(name="instanceUrl", nullable=false, strict=true, description="The instance URL")
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function postSessionAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
     ....
}
```

I send parameters as `x-www-form-urlencoded` by I want to change that to a raw format as for example:

```
{
  "veevaToken": "xxxxxx",
  "instanceUrl":"xxxxxx",
  "username":"xxxx"
}
```

How I do that? Is that possible? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST Normal raw format but in your php instead of using $_POST[name] use

```
   $http_raw = file_get_contents('php://input);
```

And that will contain the raw data which is being posted to the server that you will need to decode if its json